# Preciso de um algoritmo recursivo em Python que faça a multiplicação de dois números através de somas sucessivas

Tags: python

A multiplicação deve ser feita através de somas sucessivas, 6x4= 4+4+4+4+4+4

Entrada do programa: 6 4
Saída do programa: 24

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisará criar uma função com dois parâmetros (fator e multiplicando). No caso como a função é recursiva, eu vou nomear os parâmetros como `x` e `times`.

Dentro dessa função você deverá criar uma condicional para verificar se o parâmetro `times` é maior que zero. É esse parâmetro que dirá quantas vezes mais a função deverá ser chamada.

Se o parâmetro for maior que zero, a função deverá retornar o valor de `x` somado ao retorno da chamada da mesma função com os mesmos parâmetros, no entanto, o valor do argumento `times` deverá ter seu valor decrementado.

Se o valor da variável `times` for igual a zero, a função deverá retornar o valor zero. Dessa forma, o resultado final será a soma dos retornos de todas as chamadas até que `times` seja igual a zero.

```
def mult(x, times):   
    return x + mult(x, times - 1) if times else 0
```

Comment: Quem votou negativo poderia explicar o que está errado na resposta?

Comment: Eu não negativei, mas entendo os motivos dos negativos. A função está correta, mas a resposta é superficial. Para responder adequadamente essa pergunta você teria que introduzir o AP em Aritmetização de Linguagem para então apresentar a Teoria da Recursividade e só então Recursividade Prática. É um problema melhor trabalhado em uma sala de aula pois é uma carga teórica muito pesada. Não fique chateado, sua intenção foi ensinar ao AP a criar funções recursivas mas existem alguns axiomas que regem a definição de funções recursivas.